# Time display function not working

Tags: php, function, object, time

This code is supposed to output something like:

> You are, at this moment, living in the 11th second of the 2nd minute of the 3rd hour of the 9th day of the 5th month of the 2017th year since the begining of the International calender.

Instead it outputs this: https://prnt.sc/fli92p

Have no idea what the problem is.

```
       date_default_timezone_set(//location...); 
       say_time();

        function say_time() 
        {
            $o = ' of the';


            class time_value
            {
                public $t, $name, $display;
                protected $n, $suf;

                function __construct() 
                {
                    $this->display = " $this->n"."$this->suf"." $this->name";
                    $this->n = date($this->t,time());
                    switch ($this->n)
                    {
                            case 1:
                                $suf = 'st';
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                $suf = 'nd';
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                $suf = 'rd';
                                break;
                            default:
                                $suf = 'nth';
                                break; 
                    }
                }

            }

                $sec = new time_value;
                $sec->t = 's';
                $sec->name = 'seconds';

                $min = new time_value;
                $min->t = 'i';
                $min->name = 'minutes';

                $hr = new time_value;
                $hr->t = 'G';
                $hr->name = 'hours';

                $day = new time_value;
                $day->t = 'j';
                $day->name = 'days';

                $mon = new time_value;
                $mon->t = 'n';
                $mon->name = 'months';

                $yr = new time_value;
                $yr->t = 'Y';
                $yr->name = 'years';

                echo "You are, at this moment, living in the "
                               .$sec->display .$o
                               .$min->display .$o
                               .$hr ->display .$o 
                               .$day->display .$o
                               .$mon->display .$o
                               .$yr ->display .
                     " since the begining of the International calender.";
                echo $sec->display;
        }
```

Comment: why would you use a class in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
$this->display = " $this->n"."$this->suf"." $this->name";
```

is the first line of the class' constructor. It stores in the `$display` property of the object a string that contains only spaces because the values it contains are not set yet.

Read about [double-quotes strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and [variables parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) inside double-quotes strings.

In order to work, the class `time_value` should be like this:

```
class time_value
{
    private $t, $name, $display;

    public function __construct($t, $name)
    {
        $this->t = $t;
        $this->name = $name;

        $n = date($this->t, time());
        switch ($n)
        {
            case 1:
                $suf = 'st';
                break;
            case 2:
                $suf = 'nd';
                break;
            case 3:
                $suf = 'rd';
                break;
            default:
                $suf = 'th';
                break; 
        }

        $this->display = " {$n}{$suf} {$this->name}";
    }

    public function display() { return $this->display; }
}

$sec = new time_value('s', 'seconds');
$min = new time_value('i', 'minutes');
// all the other time components here...

echo $sec->display().$o.$min->display(); // ...
```

The next step toward object-oriented programming is to encapsulate the generation of all time components into the `time_value` class (or into another class that uses `time_value` instances, if you like it more) and have the code of function `say_time()` look like this:

```
function say_time()
{
    $time = new time_value();
    echo "You are, at this moment, living in the ".$time->display("of the")." since the begining of the International calender.";
}
```